# Help Needed Regarding View Module

Tags: views

Hi I am a newbie and want to Get Functionality from view module in the form of grid in which i want to show some fields and a main title after clicking on title user will be directed to full post. Can anyone help me how to get this functionality.
In other word i want to change the order of displaying data to end user created by the view module.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already created a view which shows nodes you want to display, in the view settings select Format > Grid, and Show > Fields in the Format area; select the fields you want to display in the Fields area.

If you want other than default sorting options use modules such as the following ones:

- the [Weight](http://drupal.org/project/weight) module (It allows you to assign weight to nodes and then sort them by that weight.)
- the [Menu Node Views](http://drupal.org/project/menu_node_views) module (If you have added your nodes to some menus, then this module allows to sort nodes in the view by that order.)

#### Note

The Menu Node Views module starts producing duplicate results, if the content of the node is translated to other languages (translated using the Entity translation module).